# Custom template with CPT doesn't display on frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, page-template

I created a WP plugin which adds a CPT and allows user to select custom template.

It was working when I used an [MVC design](https://iandunn.name/content/presentations/wp-oop-mvc/mvc.php#/) but when I moved to a new [MVC style](https://github.com/sumitpore/mvc-plugin-boilerplate-for-wordpress) it doesn't output on frontend and seems also doesn't assign custom template to page!

I used the following hooks:

```
    add_filter(
        'theme_page_templates', array( $this, 'add_new_template' )
    );

    add_filter(
        'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args',
        array( $this, 'register_project_templates' )
    );

  add_filter(
    'wp_insert_post_data', 
    array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
);

            // Add your templates to this array.
            $this->templates = array(
                'api.php' => 'API',
                'print_invoice.php' => 'Print Invoice',
                'wpc-post.php' => 'custom Post',
                'dashboard.php' => 'Dashboard',
            );

            // self::create_dashboard_page();

            add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'meta_box_visibility'));

            add_action('save_post', array($this, 'wporg_save_postdata'), 10, 2);

                    /* Filter the single_template with our custom function*/
                    add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'my_plugin_templates'));

            add_filter(
                'manage_dashboard_posts_columns',
                array($this, 'custom_post_type_columns')
            );

            add_action(
                'manage_dashboard_posts_custom_column',
                array($this, 'custom_column_content')
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code I was able to load the custom template.

```
public function register_hook_callbacks(){
                    // Enqueue Styles & Scripts.
                    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
                    array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );

add_filter('template_include', 
    array( $this, 'view_project_template') 
);
    }
```